# Uninstall Berkeley DB in ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, uninstall, berkeleydb

I installed `Berkeley DB 6.2.23` form [this tutorial](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/server/db.html). Also before it, I installed `libdb5.3` from ubuntu repositories. Now when I'm running a Perl script in command line, I got this error:

```
DB_File was build with libdb version 6.2.23, 
but you are attempting to run it with libdb version 5.3.28
Compilation failed in require at ./ROUGE-1.5.5.pl line 174.
```

I guess installation of these two packages is the problem, but during removing libdb5.3 there are many dependency error :

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 adduser : Depends: passwd (>= 1:4.1.5.1-1.1ubuntu6)
 libkf5service5 : Depends: libkf5dbusaddons5 (>= 4.97.0) but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: libkf5service-bin (= 5.18.0-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
 libpam-modules : PreDepends: libdb5.3 but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: update-motd but it is not going to be installed
 libqt5svg5 : Depends: libqt5widgets5 (>= 5.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
 libqtgui4:i386 : Depends: libsm6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
 libsm6 : Depends: libuuid1 (>= 2.16) but it is not going to be installed
 libxt6:i386 : Depends: libsm6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
 openssh-client : Depends: passwd
 procps : Depends: initscripts
 python3 : Depends: python3.5 (>= 3.5.1-2~) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libpython3-stdlib (= 3.5.1-3) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: dh-python but it is not going to be installed
 python3-requests : Depends: python3-urllib3 (>= 1.13.1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: python3-chardet but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: python3-urllib3 (< 1.13.2) but it is not going to be installed
 wget : Depends: libuuid1 (>= 2.16) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Because of that, I want to uninstall version 6.2.23 from my system, and want to know how can I do it.

Comment: Did you check https://askubuntu.com/questions/336795/ubuntu-fix-dependency-problems?

Answer (score 0):

I has solved the problem that you met. Because the database has some dependencies, it is hard to install the database with a usual way. You need to install the database according to the following guidelines.

**1. Install berkeley-db**

Please install the berkeley-db with the commands as follows :

```
$ wget http://download.oracle.com/berkeley-db/db-4.8.30.zip
$ unzip db-4.8.30.zip
$ cd db-4.8.30/
$ cd build_unix/
$ ../dist/configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-cxx
$ make -j12
$ make install
$ sudo make install
```

The above commands enable to install the libraries that the following bsddb3 needs.

**2. Install bsddb3-6.26 :**

```
$ wget https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e9/fc/ebfbd4de236b493f9ece156f816c21df0ae87ccc22604c5f9b664efef1b9/bsddb3-6.2.6.tar.gz
$ tar -xvzf bsddb3-6.2.6.tar.gz
$ cd bsddb3-6.2.6/
$ python setup.py install --berkeley-db=/usr/local/
```

After completing the installation, it will show the following message.
Processing dependencies for bsddb3==6.2.6 Finished processing dependencies for bsddb3==6.2.6.

Cheers,

Mike