# Unable to install 32bit libraries for Android studio

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, 64-bit, android-studio

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 64bit OS and I cannot install 32 bit libraries for Android studio. It shows my packages are broken.  I don't know how to install following code.  It shows dependency issue.

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0
Building dependency tree
       
Reading state information... Done

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.

The following information may help to resolve the situation:



The following packages have unmet dependencies:

 lib32bz2-1.0 : PreDepends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.9-18) but it is not going to be installed

 lib32ncurses5 : Depends: lib32tinfo5 (= 5.9+20140118-1ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed

                 Depends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed

 lib32stdc++6 : Depends: lib32gcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed

                Depends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.17) but it is not going to be installed

 lib32z1 : Depends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
```

Anyone can help me please.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14.04.  64 bit OS.

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding the 32bit architecture in dpkg - `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`, or you could try editing your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, adding the Ubuntu 12.04 repository, and running `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: Hi Gret Otten! Thanks for you reply.

I tried 'sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386' and I also run 'sudo apt-get update' after running above command, but it would not work for me.

I cannot run 'sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6' to install 32bit binaries for Android Studio.  Please help me to install android studio.

Comment: Try running "sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list", here you'll find the sources for Ubuntu 14.04. Copy the Universe and the Multiverse repo's, paste them at the end of the file, then modify "trusty" into "precise", then press CTRL+X, then +Y, so you it'll save up the file. Run "sudo apt-get update" afterwards, and try installing the packages again. It might not work with the trusty sources as some packages have not been updated yet, or will never be updated for newer Ubuntu versions. The same thing happened with the "lsb-core" package, 16.04 - 14.04. Hope this helps, if not, I'm here!

Comment: My sources.list sources:
'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe main restricted multiverse',
'deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe main restricted multiverse #Added by software-properties',
'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise universe main restricted multiverse',
'deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise universe main restricted multiverse #Added by software-properties', after I changed my sources list then I ran 'sudo apt-get update', then I installed 'sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6'.  It wont work.

Comment: Hi Gret! Please give me a solution to fix this issue.

Comment: Hi Gret! Finally I found the solution from this link: 'http://askubuntu.com/questions/336795/ubuntu-fix-dependency-problems' its installed my dependency packages for Android Studio.  Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Ah, the Debian repo. That should do fine, since Ubuntu is based on Debian. Glad I could help! Like I said, using different repositories might work just fine.