# Can't install package because of unsatisfied dependency even though dependency is installed

Tags: package-management, dependencies

OS: Ubuntu 17.10 64bits

I am trying to install splashtop streamer, which was last updated for Ubuntu 14.04. It needed libx264-142 and wouldn't want to install using the newer libx264-148 version. So I went to the ubuntu website and downloaded the 142 version that the package asked for, and after installing it the package still refuses to install and still throws "dependency could not be satisfied: libx264-142"

Synaptics shows that both libx264-142 AND libx264-148 are installed. I was going to try to uninstall the 148 variant to see if that helped my package "see" the 142 version, but it wanted to unistall a lot of other packages so I decided against that. Is there a way to manually point it to the package it needs?

Comment: this is a total guess .. but it should work .. you can try `sudo dpkg -i --force-all package.deb` of course change package.deb to the actual deb file

Comment: It installed it but the program is not working. The terminal output said that "dependency problem, but configuring anyway as you requested" and then listed all of the dependencies. I manually installed all of the dependencies using synaptics but for some reason the package can't see them, since even the GUI is botchered. Would adding the thrusty repository solve this? Is it possible to add that in order to install the program and then remove the repository?

Comment: sorry as i said it was a guess .. you can try to look into this .. maybe it can help `https://askubuntu.com/questions/336795/ubuntu-fix-dependency-problems` not exactly your issue .. but maybe it will give you a starting point

Comment: it may be as simple as running `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: No, you cannot manually edit dependencies. Full stop. This seems like a Splashtop support question ("Please package for 17.10") or bug report ("Dependencies are broken") instead of an Ubuntu support question - it's not in the Ubuntu Repositories. It is unwise to install packages onto the wrong release of Ubuntu for exactly the reasons you are encountering. Consider installing from source instead of packages...or use a supported application instead.

Comment: I don't know of any suitable alternative. I use heavily splashtop and I didn't have this issue with 16.04. When using that release, I simply installed the libx264-142 package that I downloaded from the thrusty archive, and it would install fine. This is why I doubt it's a problem with the package itself. This is not working on 17.10 specifically.