# how to install java 8 32 in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation, 18.04, java

i have downloaded the java 8 32 bit "jdk-8u171-linux-i586.tar.gz" and i have extract the folder "jdk1.8.0_171". Here my question is how to install jdk1.8.0_171

Please help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Use this repository for installing Java 8 without that tar.gz nonsense 
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java`
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer`
I still can't believe that Oracle is not going to provide an official .deb file.

Answer (score 0):

follow
[Ubuntu fix dependency problems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/336795/ubuntu-fix-dependency-problems)
then

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```