# Struggling to install package via apt-get or Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: apt, dpkg

OS: ubuntu 14.04 LTS

```
$ uname -a
Linux egorov 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

My goal: To install `libass-dev` package via `apt-get` or Software Center

#### Problem description:

When I try

```
$ sudo apt-get install libass-dev
```

I'm getting

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libass-dev : Depends: libfreetype6-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libfontconfig1-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When I try "Ubuntu Software Center" -> "libass-dev" -> "install" following error appears:

[image]

This is not the only package with such problems. MB smth wrong with my app repo.

I tried:

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get -u dist-upgrade
```

and some similar advices but none of them helped.

Comment: You're right - the problem is with your "app repo," and none of those commands will fix problems with an "app repo". Please edit your question to include the complete output of `sudo apt update` and `apt-cache policy libass-dev` and `apt-cache policy ibfreetype6-dev`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @user535733, @N0rbert and @karel

This info solved the issue:

[Ubuntu fix dependency problems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/336795/ubuntu-fix-dependency-problems)

Probably this question should be marked as duplicate