# Ubuntu 18.04 can't re-install Nginx

Tags: apt, server, package-management, dpkg, nginx

I cant install any dependency or package on my ubuntu server.

I've tried removing Nginx and all it's components.

I've tried reinstalling it multiple times

I've tried stopping Apache and Nginx

And I've tried restarting the server.

I keep getting the following message:

```
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript nginx, action "start" failed.
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-09-08 21:56:04 BST; 12ms ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
  Process: 88379 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1802 (code=killed, signal=KILL)

Sep 08 21:56:04 Linux systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Sep 08 21:56:04 Linux nginx[88379]: nginx: [emerg] dlopen() "/usr/share/nginx/modules/ngx_http_geoip_module.so" failed (/usr/share/nginx/modules/ngx_http_geoip_module.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-geoip.conf:1
Sep 08 21:56:04 Linux nginx[88379]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Sep 08 21:56:04 Linux systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep 08 21:56:04 Linux systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.


Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
dpkg: error processing package nginx-core (--configure):
 installed nginx-core package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nginx:
 nginx depends on nginx-core (<< 1.14.0-0ubuntu1.7.1~) | nginx-full (<< 1.14.0-0ubuntu1.7.1~) | nginx-light (<< 1.14.0-0ubuntu1.7.1~) | nginx-extras (<< 1.14.0-0ubuntu1.7.1~); however:
  Package nginx-core is not configured yet.
  Package nginx-full is not installed.
  Package nginx-light is not installed.
  Package nginx-extras is not installed.
 nginx depends on nginx-core (>= 1.14.0-0ubuntu1.7) | nginx-full (>= 1.14.0-0ubuntu1.7) | nginx-light (>= 1.14.0-0ubuntu1.7) | nginx-extras (>= 1.14.0-0ubuntu1.7); however:
  Package nginx-core is not configured yet.
  Package nginx-full is not installed.
  Package nginx-light is not installed.
  Package nginx-extras is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package nginx (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for ufw (0.36-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-21) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.42) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nginx-core
 nginx
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How do I fix this warning and reinstall nginx?

added `apt install libnginx-mod-http-geoip` response

```
root@Linux:/etc/nginx/modules-enabled# apt install libnginx-mod-http-geoip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libnginx-mod-http-geoip is already the newest version (1.14.0-0ubuntu1.7).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-azure-5.3-cloud-tools-5.3.0-1035 linux-azure-5.3-tools-5.3.0-1035 linux-cloud-tools-5.3.0-1035-azure linux-image-5.3.0-1035-azure linux-modules-5.3.0-1035-azure linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-1035-azure
  linux-tools-5.3.0-1035-azure
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up nginx-core (1.14.0-0ubuntu1.7) ...
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript nginx, action "start" failed.
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-09-08 22:20:40 BST; 11ms ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
  Process: 115846 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1802 (code=killed, signal=KILL)

Sep 08 22:20:40 Linux systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Sep 08 22:20:40 Linux nginx[115846]: nginx: [emerg] dlopen() "/usr/share/nginx/modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so" failed (/usr/share/nginx/modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-image-filter.conf:1
Sep 08 22:20:40 Linux nginx[115846]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Sep 08 22:20:40 Linux systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep 08 22:20:40 Linux systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 08 22:20:40 Linux systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
dpkg: error processing package nginx-core (--configure):
 installed nginx-core package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nginx-core
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@RapioLinux:/etc/nginx/modules-enabled#
```

also running `sudo apt-get install nginx-full` returns

```
root@Linux:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled# sudo apt-get install nginx-full nginx-light nginx-extras
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nginx-extras : Conflicts: nginx-full but 1.14.0-0ubuntu1.7 is to be installed
                Conflicts: nginx-light but 1.14.0-0ubuntu1.7 is to be installed
 nginx-full : Conflicts: nginx-extras but 1.14.0-0ubuntu1.7 is to be installed
              Conflicts: nginx-light but 1.14.0-0ubuntu1.7 is to be installed
 nginx-light : Conflicts: nginx-extras but 1.14.0-0ubuntu1.7 is to be installed
               Conflicts: nginx-full but 1.14.0-0ubuntu1.7 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Did you try "the usual stuff" to fix dependency problems? [Ubuntu fix dependency problems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/336795/ubuntu-fix-dependency-problems)

Comment: Yes, doesn't help

Comment: `grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/` please and `dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `libnginx-mod-http-geoip` is missing.
Try to install [it](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libnginx-mod-http-geoip/filelist)

```
apt install libnginx-mod-http-geoip
```

than re-install nginx

Comment: Doesn't work either. I cant install any package

Comment: try to fix with `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, maybe you will need to delete  file `/etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-geoip.conf`

Comment: it returns `Errors were encountered while processing:
 nginx-core`

Comment: Delete `/etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-geoip.conf` and try again

Comment: Same issue as before

Comment: Could you add post install output to the question?

Comment: Added it to the question

Comment: Well, please delete all config files at `/etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf` and try to reinstall

Comment: it works but as soon as I ran `sudo apt-get install nginx-full ` the problem returned

Comment: You don't need all meta packages `nginx-full` `nginx-light` `nginx-extras`. Remove `/etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf` configs, purge all packages `sudo apt-get purge nginx-full nginx-light nginx-extras` and just install `sudo apt-get install nginx`

Comment: what about nginx-core?

Comment: It'll be installed as dependency

Comment: Oke, thanks! I'm still getting erros but that's a whole different story

Comment: You are welcome )